# Add css library to Squarespace

Tags: squarespace

I am currently stuck trying to add animate on scroll to my squarespace code. I have tried adding the cdn as well as trying to add a document link via text hyperlink. Does anyone know how to add this library  https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/ to squarespace either cdn or another way. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few ways you could do this, although I'm not sure why it hasn't worked for you yet. Can you provide more info or link to your live page?

If you don't care about adding to load times you can just use a `<link>` or `<script>`tag in between your `<head>` tags by using Squarespace's Code Injector like in AOS's documentation:

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then add the js to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="bower_components/aos/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

You'll want to make sure you init the js later on when the script is loaded by injecting the init code in your `<footer>` through the Code Injector:

```
  <script> 
     AOS.init(); 
  </script>
```

Another option if you're optimizing loads more (which you should do) is to build a small node.js app with your customizations and roll AOS into it. You could use Jason Barone's [Squarespace Template Helper](https://github.com/Squarefront/squarespace-template-helper) to get started with this.

After you clone the repo locally (which has node package manager installed) you can `cd` to the directory and `npm install aos --save` then `npm i`. If you have issues try running `npm run postinstall`.

You then add all your animations and [upload the compiled app to Squarespace](https://github.com/Squarefront/squarespace-template-helper#using-your-custom-javascript-in-squarespace-without-developer-mode).